# Hormones and body mass

Tags: food, endocrinology, nutrition, muscles, amino-acids

I was wondering how some animals (bulls, elephants etc.) become so large by only eating grass or plant based material and why some humans can build large amounts of muscle and mass without a proper diet. 
1. How do both get their essential amino acids in order to build muscle and mass?
2. Can hormones independently build muscle and mass regardless of the food or amount of calories ingested?

Comment: All life has amino acids. That bulls and elephants are alive suggests that they can obtain any amino acids that they can't synthesise from their diet.

Comment: hormones are only signals - how the organism responds to hormones is tuned by evolution in each organism.

Comment: The amino acids to build muscle and lean mass come from essential amino acids that must be consumed via diet that contains these, which most plants do not.

Comment: Could more hormones then possibly send a signal to extract more nutritious material from food in order to build more mass?